# How can we handle SeekBar in Appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium

[image]I wrote a code for SeekBar.

I wanted to move the SeekBar but it did not move.

When I run the code it gives me values in the console but did not move.

Kindly check my code and tell me what I am missing in this,

```
    Base.java ;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
    
    public class base {
        
        public static  AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException
        {
            
             File f = new File("src");
             File fs = new File(f, "tesjo.apk");
            
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Galaxy A10s");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Uiautomator2");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "10");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
             cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "C:/Users/LENOVO L540/Downloads/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe");
                
            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
            
                     
             return driver ;
            
    
        }
    
    }



Tesjocalss ;

import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions.longPressOptions;

import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;


public class demotesjo extends base {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>driver=capabilities();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElementById("com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_foreground_only_button").click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.mytesjo.android:id/nav_bottom_profile")).click();
        driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Email\")").sendKeys("hamza@student.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Password']")).sendKeys("12345678");
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.mytesjo.android:id/login_student_RB")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.mytesjo.android:id/login_BTN")).click();
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.mytesjo.android:id/nav_bottom_home")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Teacher']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        
        MobileElement seekBar = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.mytesjo.android:id/price_seekbar");
        
// get start co-ordinate of seekbar
    int start = seekBar.getLocation().getX();
    System.out.println(start);
    // Get width of seekbar
    int end = seekBar.getSize().getWidth();
    System.out.println(end);
    // get location of seekbar vertically
    int y = seekBar.getLocation().getY();
    System.out.println(start);

    // Select till which position you want to move the seekbar
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

    // Move it 40%
    int moveToXDirectionAt = (int) (end * 0.4);
    System.out.println("Moving seek bar at " + moveToXDirectionAt+" In X direction.");
    action.longPress(PointOption.point(start,y)) .moveTo(PointOption.point(moveToXDirectionAt,y)) .release().perform();
    
  
        }
         
        
        
        
    }



console output ,
0
720
0
Moving seek bar at 288 In X direction.
```

Comment: please add the screen shot of the element and activity

Comment: @PDHide kindly check

Answer (score 1):

```
 action.longPress(PointOption.point(0, y)).moveTo(PointOption.point(moveToXDirectionAt, y)).release().perform();
```

your code is correct , the issue is the starting position i guess. Start from zero